# Querying "standard meta tags" for their tag wikis wrongly says they have none

Tags: bug, status-completed, api, meta, tag-wiki

I'm checking which tags have tag wiki excerpts in my code. It looks like [`/tags/{tags}/wikis`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wikis-by-tags) is the right API since the tag info API doesn't even give a boolean for tag wiki excerpt presence.

But there's a bug where the tag wiki excerpts are not returned for the "standard meta tags": `support`, `discussion`, `featured`, `bug`. (I'm not sure if others are also affected.) These seem to be the tags with either/both of the `is_required` and `is_moderator_only` flags.

> [`/2.1/tags/support;discussion;featured;bug/wikis?site=meta.travel`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wikis-by-tags#tags=support;discussion;featured&filter=default&site=meta.travel&run=true)

Returns:

```
{
  "items": [],
  "quota_remaining": 9895,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "has_more": false
}
```

If it's by design that I can't retrieve the tag wiki excerpts for these then it leaves no way to distinguish between tags of this sort and tags which lack a wiki excerpt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixed as of the latest build.

Default tag wikis are a bit special behind the scenes, and the API simply wasn't looking for them at all.